# Mobile Carrier Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript

So it appears that T-Mobile in the UK are injecting a javascript file into the head of files that are transfered over their mobile data network.

The file in question is 1.2.3.8/bmi-int-js/bmi.js (contents below)

My question is this

> How does one defend (an app/website) against a carrier injected attack like this?

I use the term attack carefully as I'm sure they would claim they do nothing nefarious and that it is actually used to speedup delivery over a mobile network but it is:

1. breaking javascript left right and centre.
2. makes your server look like its been hacked - until you notice the 1.2.3.8/ part of the URL
3. stops your app/website from working

I have jQuery based app and in its simplest form it has brown the http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap javascript plugins.

Code from the bmi file below:

**Editnote:** Edited code below with indentation and line breaks to make is readable.

```
var bmi_htmlEdit = 0;
var bmi_ie;
var bmi_ns;
var bmi_safari;
var bmi_imageObjSelected;
var bmi_ffx_op_toolTip = "Shift+R improves the quality of this image. Shift+A improves the quality of all images on this page.";
var bmi_toolTip = "Shift+R improves the quality of this image. CTRL+F5 reloads the whole page.";
var bmi_ns_tooltip = "Shift+Reload reloads the whole page.";
var bmi_toolTipSeperator = " ... ";
var bmi_concatStr = "bmi_orig_img";
var bmi_frameNotAllowed;
var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_major = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
var is_minor = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var bmi_ns = ((agt.indexOf('mozilla') != -1) && (agt.indexOf('spoofer') == -1) && (agt.indexOf('compatible') == -1) && (agt.indexOf('opera') == -1) && (agt.indexOf('webtv') == -1) && (agt.indexOf('hotjava') == -1));
var bmi_ns2 = (bmi_ns && (is_major == 2));
var bmi_ns3 = (bmi_ns && (is_major == 3));
var bmi_ns4 = (bmi_ns && (is_major == 4));
var bmi_ns4up = (bmi_ns && (is_major >= 4));
var bmi_nsonly = (bmi_ns && ((agt.indexOf(";nav") != -1) || (agt.indexOf("; nav") != -1) || (agt.indexOf("Netscape") != -1) || (agt.indexOf("netscape") != -1)));
var bmi_ns6 = (bmi_ns && (is_major == 5));
var bmi_ns6up = (bmi_ns && (is_major >= 5));
var is_gecko = (agt.indexOf('gecko') != -1);
var bmi_firefox = (agt.indexOf('firefox') != -1);
var bmi_safari = (agt.indexOf('applewebkit') != -1);
var bmi_ie = ((agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) && (agt.indexOf("opera") == -1));
var bmi_ie3 = (bmi_ie && (is_major < 4));
var bmi_ie4 = (bmi_ie && (is_major == 4) && (agt.indexOf("msie 4") != -1));
var bmi_ie4up = (bmi_ie && (is_major >= 4));
var bmi_ie5 = (bmi_ie && (is_major == 4) && (agt.indexOf("msie 5.0") != -1));
var bmi_ie5_5 = (bmi_ie && (is_major == 4) && (agt.indexOf("msie 5.5") != -1));
var bmi_ie5up = (bmi_ie && !bmi_ie3 && !bmi_ie4);
var bmi_ie5_5up = (bmi_ie && !bmi_ie3 && !bmi_ie4 && !bmi_ie5);
var bmi_ie6 = (bmi_ie && (is_major == 4) && (agt.indexOf("msie 6.") != -1));
var bmi_ie6up = (bmi_ie && !bmi_ie3 && !bmi_ie4 && !bmi_ie5 && !bmi_ie5_5);
var bmi_opera = (agt.indexOf("opera") != -1);
var bmi_opera2 = (agt.indexOf("opera 2") != -1 || agt.indexOf("opera/2") != -1);
var bmi_opera3 = (agt.indexOf("opera 3") != -1 || agt.indexOf("opera/3") != -1);
var bmi_opera4 = (agt.indexOf("opera 4") != -1 || agt.indexOf("opera/4") != -1);
var bmi_opera5 = (agt.indexOf("opera 5") != -1 || agt.indexOf("opera/5") != -1);
var bmi_opera5up = (bmi_opera && !bmi_opera2 && !bmi_opera3 && !bmi_opera4);

function bmi_checkAccess(win) {
    bmi_frameNotAllowed = 0;
    window.bmioldOnError = window.onerror;
    window.onerror = null;
    try {
        var l = win.location.href;
    } catch (e) {
        bmi_frameNotAllowed = 1;
    }
    if (bmi_frameNotAllowed == 1) {
        window.onerror = window.bmioldOnError;
        return false;
    } else {
        window.onerror = window.bmioldOnError;
        return true;
    }
}

function bmi_ImageElement(el) {
    if (!el) return 0;
    var str = new String(el.tagName);
    if (str.match("IMG")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (str.match("INPUT")) {
        if (el.type && bmi_checkInputType(el.type)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if (str.match("OBJECT")) {
        if (el.type && bmi_checkMIMEType(el.type)) {
            el.bmi_objTag = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (str.match("EMBED")) {
        if (el.type && bmi_checkMIMEType(el.type)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (str.match("AREA") || str.match("A")) {
        var p = el.parentNode;
        if (p && (p.tagName == "MAP") && (p.bmi_imgObj != null)) {
            el.bmi_mapImage = p.bmi_imgObj;
            p.bmi_imgObj.bmi_areaEl = el;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function bmi_resetTitle(el) {
    if (!el) return;
    if (el.bmi_touched != 1) return;
    el.title = "";
    if (el.bmi_oldTitle) {
        el.title = el.bmi_oldTitle;
        if (el.bmi_oldAlt) {
            el.alt = el.bmi_oldAlt;
        }
    } else if (el.bmi_oldAlt) {
        el.alt = el.bmi_oldAlt;
        if (bmi_ie) el.title = el.alt;
    }
    if (el.bmi_gotOriginal) {
        if (el.bmi_orig_mouseout) {
            el.onmouseout = el.bmi_orig_mouseout;
        }
    }
}

function bmi_checkElement(el) {
    var pwindow = null;
    if (el.bmi_gotOriginal) return;
    if (el.bmi_mapImage) {
        if (el.bmi_mapImage.bmi_gotOriginal == 1) {
            el.bmi_gotOriginal = 1;
            if (el.bmi_touched) bmi_resetTitle(el);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (el.bmi_touched != 1) {
        bmi_setElementTitle(el);
        if (el.onmouseout) {
            el.bmi_orig_mouseout = el.onmouseout;
            el.onmouseout = bmi_safeMouseOutEvents;
        } else {
            el.onmouseout = bmi_safeMouseOutEvents;
        }
    } else {
        el.title = el.bmi_title;
        el.alt = el.bmi_alt;
    }
    if (el.bmi_mapImage) bmi_imageObjSelected = el.bmi_mapImage;
    else bmi_imageObjSelected = el;
    if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) pwindow = document.parentWindow;
    else if (bmi_nsonly || is_gecko) pwindow = document.defaultView;
    else pwindow = null;
    if (pwindow && (pwindow != pwindow.parent)) {
        pwindow.focus();
        el.bmi_changedFocus = 1;
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_setElementTitle(el) {
    var tmpAlt = "";
    if (el.alt) {
        tmpAlt = el.alt;
        el.bmi_oldAlt = el.alt;
        el.bmi_alt = "";
        el.alt = "";
    }
    if (el.title) {
        el.bmi_oldTitle = el.title;
        el.title = el.title + "";
    } else {
        el.title = tmpAlt + "";
    }
    if (bmi_firefox) {
        el.title = el.title + bmi_toolTipSeperator + bmi_ffx_op_toolTip;
        el.bmi_touched = 1;
        el.bmi_title = el.title;
    } else if (bmi_opera || bmi_safari) {
        el.title = bmi_ffx_op_toolTip;
        el.bmi_touched = 1;
        el.bmi_title = el.title;
    } else {
        el.title = el.title + bmi_toolTipSeperator + bmi_toolTip;
        el.bmi_touched = 1;
        el.bmi_title = el.title;
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_checkInputType(type) {
    if (!type) return 0;
    if (type.match("image") || type.match("Image")) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function bmi_checkMIMEType(type) {
    var typeStr = new String(type);
    var find = /image\//gi;
    if (typeStr.search(find) != -1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

function bmi_mouseOver(e) {
    bmi_imageObjSelected = null;
    var obj;
    if (document.bmi_onmouseover_original != null) document.bmi_onmouseover_original(e);
    if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) {
        var e = window.event;
        obj = e.srcElement;
    } else {
        obj = e.target;
    }
    if (obj.bmi_gotOriginal) return;
    if (bmi_ImageElement(obj)) {
        bmi_checkElement(obj);
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_safeMouseOutEvents(e) {
    var obj;
    if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) {
        e = window.event;
        obj = e.srcElement;
    } else {
        obj = e.target;
    }
    bmi_resetTitle(obj);
    if (obj.bmi_changedFocus == 1) {
        var pwindow = null;
        if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) pwindow = document.parentWindow;
        else if (bmi_nsonly || is_gecko) pwindow = document.defaultView;
        else pwindow = null;
        if (pwindow) {
            pwindow.top.focus();
            obj.bmi_changedFocus = 0;
        }
    }
    if (obj.bmi_orig_mouseout) {
        obj.bmi_orig_mouseout();
    }
}

function bmi_updateImageSrc(src) {
    var found = 0;
    var find = /\?/g;
    var editUrl;
    var editIndex;
    var editProto;
    var bmiSignIndex;
    var bmiSign;
    srcString = new String(src);
    if (srcString.search(find) != -1) {
        found = 1;
        srcString = srcString.concat("&" + bmi_concatStr + "=1");
    } else {
        var i = srcString.lastIndexOf("/");
        var newStr = srcString.substring(i + 1);
        srcString = srcString.concat("/" + bmi_concatStr + "/" + newStr);
    }
    if (bmi_htmlEdit) {
        editIndex = srcString.indexOf("://");
        if (editIndex != -1) {
            editProto = srcString.substring(0, editIndex + 3);
            editUrl = srcString.substring(editIndex + 3);
            editIndex = editUrl.indexOf("/");
            if (editIndex != -1) {
                editUrl = editUrl.substring(editIndex + 1);
                bmiSignIndex = editUrl.indexOf("/");
                if (bmiSignIndex != -1) {
                    bmiSign = editUrl.substring(0, bmiSignIndex);
                    if (bmiSign == "bmi") {
                        editUrl = editUrl.substring(bmiSignIndex + 1);
                        srcString = editProto + editUrl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (srcString);
}

function bmi_replaceImages(array) {
    if (!array) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].bmi_gotOriginal) {
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i].bmi_objTag) {
            array[i].data = bmi_updateImageSrc(array[i].data);
        } else {
            array[i].src = bmi_updateImageSrc(array[i].src);
        }
        array[i].bmi_gotOriginal = 1;
        if (array[i].bmi_touched) {
            bmi_resetTitle(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_replaceInputImages(array) {
    if (!array) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].bmi_gotOriginal) {
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i].type && bmi_checkInputType(array[i].type)) {
            array[i].src = bmi_updateImageSrc(array[i].src);
            array[i].bmi_gotOriginal = 1;
            if (array[i].bmi_touched) {
                bmi_resetTitle(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_NSlayers() {
    if (document != null) {
        if (!document.layers) {
            bmi_replaceImages(document.tags.IMG);
            bmi_replaceInputImages(document.tags.INPUT);
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < document.layers.length; i++) {
            bmi_NSlayers(document.layers[i].document);
            bmi_replaceImages(document.layers[i].document.tags.IMG);
            bmi_replaceInputImages(document.layers[i].document.tags.INPUT);
        }
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_downloadAllHandler() {
    if ((true == bmi_checkAccess(parent)) && (parent.location.href != self.location.href)) {
        var newparent = parent;
        do {
            newparent = newparent.parent;
            if ((false == bmi_checkAccess(newparent.parent)) || (newparent.parent.location.href == newparent.location.href)) {
                break;
            }
        } while (newparent); //
        var numFrames = newparent.frames.length;
        var index = 0;
        var frame;
        for (; index < newparent.frames.length; index++) {
            frame = newparent.frames[index];
            if (false == bmi_checkAccess(frame.window)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (frame.window.bmi_reDownloadAllImages) {
                frame.window.bmi_reDownloadAllImages();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    bmi_reDownloadAllImages();
}

function bmi_reDownloadAllImages() {
    var imgArray;
    var inputArray;
    var backgroundArray;
    var numFrames = window.frames.length;
    var index = 0;
    var frame;
    for (; index < numFrames; index++) {
        frame = window.frames[index];
        if (false == bmi_checkAccess(frame.window)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (frame.window.bmi_reDownloadAllImages) {
            frame.window.bmi_reDownloadAllImages();
        }
    }
    if ((bmi_ie5up || bmi_ns6up || bmi_opera5up || bmi_firefox)) {
        imgArray = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
        inputArray = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        bmi_replaceImages(imgArray);
        bmi_replaceInputImages(inputArray);
    } else if (bmi_ns && (bmi_ns4 || bmi_ns3)) {
        var imgArray;
        var docLayers;
        docLayers = document.layers;
        if (docLayers && docLayers.length) {
            for (var layi = 0; layi < 0; layi++) {
                imgArray = docLayers[layi].document.images;
                bmi_replaceImages(imgArray);
            }
        } else {
            imgArray = document.images;
            bmi_replaceImages(imgArray);
        }
    } else {
        imgArray = document.images;
        bmi_replaceImages(imgArray);
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_reDownloadSelectedImage(img) {
    if (img.bmi_gotOriginal) {
        return;
    }
    if (img && !img.bmi_gotOriginal) {
        if (img.bmi_objTag) {
            img.data = bmi_updateImageSrc(img.data);
        } else {
            img.src = bmi_updateImageSrc(img.src);
        }
        img.bmi_gotOriginal = 1;
        if (img.bmi_touched) {
            bmi_resetTitle(img);
        }
        if (img.bmi_areaEl && (img.bmi_areaEl.bmi_touched)) {
            bmi_resetTitle(img.bmi_areaEl);
            img.bmi_areaEl.bmi_gotOriginal = 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_keypress(e) {
    var reloadSingle = 0;
    var reloadAll = 0;
    var obj;
    if (bmi_ns) {
        if (bmi_ns6up) {
            if ((String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) == 'r') || (String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) == 'R')) reloadSingle = 1;
            else {
                if ((String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) == 'A')) reloadAll = 1;
            }
            obj = e.target;
            var str = new String(obj.tagName);
            if (str.match("INPUT") && (bmi_checkInputType(obj.type) != 1)) {
                if (bmi_imageObjSelected == obj) reloadAll = reloadSingle = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if ((String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 'R') && (e.modifiers == Event.SHIFT_MASK)) reloadSingle = 1;
            else {
                if ((String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 'A') && (e.modifiers == Event.SHIFT_MASK)) reloadAll = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) {
        if ((String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode) == 'R') && (window.event.shiftKey)) reloadSingle = 1;
        else if (bmi_opera) {
            if ((String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode) == 'A') && (window.event.shiftKey)) reloadAll = 1;
        }
        var e = window.event;
        obj = e.srcElement;
        var str = new String(obj.tagName);
        if (str.match("INPUT") && (bmi_checkInputType(obj.type) != 1)) {
            if (bmi_imageObjSelected == obj) reloadSingle = reloadAll = 0;
        }
    }
    if (reloadSingle == 1) {
        if (bmi_ns) {
            if (bmi_ns4 || bmi_ns3 || bmi_ns2) {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (bmi_imageObjSelected) bmi_reDownloadSelectedImage(bmi_imageObjSelected);
    } else {
        if (reloadAll == 1) {
            bmi_downloadAllHandler();
        }
    }
    if ((document.bmi_onkeypress_original != null) && (document.bmi_onkeypress_original != bmi_keypress)) {
        return (document.bmi_onkeypress_original(e));
    }
    return;
}

function bmi_linkMapImages(maps, objs) {
    var linked = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        if (linked >= maps.length) {
            return linked;
        }
        if (objs[i].useMap) {
            var newStr = new String(objs[i].useMap);
            var mapName = newStr.substring(newStr.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
            if (bmi_ImageElement(objs[i]) != 1) continue;
            for (var j = 0; j < maps.length; j++) {
                if (maps[j].name == mapName) {
                    maps[j].bmi_imgObj = objs[i];
                    linked++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return linked;
}

function bmi_load() {
    if (bmi_orig_onLoad) {
        bmi_orig_onLoad();
    }
    if (bmi_ns2 || bmi_ns3 || bmi_ns4) {
        window.defaultStatus = bmi_ns_tooltip;
        return;
    }
    if (document.onmouseover) {
        if (document.onmouseover != bmi_mouseOver) {
            document.bmi_onmouseover_original = document.onmouseover;
        }
    }
    document.onmouseover = bmi_mouseOver;
    if (document.onkeypress) {
        if (document.onkeypress != bmi_keypress) {
            document.bmi_onkeypress_original = document.onkeypress;
        }
    } else {
        document.bmi_onkeypress_original = null;
    }
    document.onkeypress = bmi_keypress;
    var maps = document.getElementsByTagName("MAP");
    if ((maps == null) || (maps.length == 0)) {
        return;
    }
    var objs = null;
    if (bmi_ie || bmi_opera) {
        objs = document.all;
        if (objs) {
            bmi_linkMapImages(maps, objs);
        }
    }
    if (bmi_ns || is_gecko) {
        var num = 0;
        objs = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
        if (objs) {
            num = num + bmi_linkMapImages(maps, objs);
        }
        if (num >= maps.length) {
            return;
        }
        objs = null;
        objs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        if (objs) {
            num += bmi_linkMapImages(maps, objs);
        }
        if (num >= maps.length) {
            return;
        }
        objs = null;
        objs = document.getElementsByTagName("OBJECT");
        if (objs) {
            num += bmi_linkMapImages(maps, objs);
        }
    }
    return;
}
var bmi_orig_onLoad;

function bmi_SafeAddOnload(f, urlStr, htmlEdit) {
    if (urlStr) {
        bmi_concatStr = urlStr;
    }
    if (htmlEdit) {
        bmi_htmlEdit = htmlEdit;
    }
    if (bmi_ie4) {
        window.onload = f;
    } else if (window.onload) {
        if (window.onload != f) {
            bmi_orig_onLoad = window.onload;
            window.onload = f;
        }
    } else {
        window.onload = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know how to defend against it, I think security.se is your best bet. But if youw ant to know how to negate its effects, then SO is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is more of a programming question than a server question, but...

You can't for a non-SSL/TLS secured site.  And even then depending on how the network handles traffic, you might be out of luck.  Opera notoriously proxies your traffic to them, then sets up the SSL/TLS connection from their servers to your intended destination.  They then, have the ability to inject code after it comes out of the secure connection.

So if the ISP in question is proxying traffic even to the point of proxying SSL/TLS, you'll never be able to prevent them from doing code injections to a random user of that ISP.  If they're not, then using SSL/TLS will prevent that code from being injected.

You're asking how to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, basically, but when the man-in-the-middle is the ISP and controls the infrastructure, that can be nigh-impossible.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone thru this rather quickly but these are some of the things I was able to get from it:

This script reduces the quality of the images on the website, to reduce the load time an cost of displaying the page on your mobile browser. If more sites would be mobile friendly, they wouldn't need to do this. Unfortunately still a lot of people do not optimize for mobile.

As to avoiding this: HTTPS, proxies, ...

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me to see the carrier do a MITM attack on SSL though.

Comment: @ceejayoz That's when it's important to trust the source of your phone's trusted roots - carrier-molested Android installs come to mind, with all this CarrierIQ news floating around..

Answer (score 4):

My sympathies; this is somewhat sleazy behavior on the part of the mobile carrier.  The most robust way to prevent it is to use SSL/TLS (i.e., HTTPS).  I think it is unlikely that the carrier is going to try to mount a man-in-the-middle attack on SSL/TLS traffic (both because of social pressure, and because if they were to do so, they would trigger cert warnings all over the place), so I think this should be pretty effective.  It is unfortunate that you have to go to those lengths to protect the integrity of your traffic, though.

You might also be interested in EFF's [Test Your ISP](https://www.eff.org/testyourisp) project, which is concerned with detecting and publicizing cases of tampering with your packets by your ISP/carrier.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask nice proxies not to modify your HTTP traffic by using a standard HTTP header:

```
Cache-Control: no-transform
```

This particular proxy (which is probably [ByteMobile](http://www.citrix.com/products/bytemobile/overview.html)) respects it.

To *defend* from such modifications you must use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

What the script is doing appears to be well intentioned.

That they have implemented this without users' knowledge and a clear option to opt-out is IMHO a clear violation of your privacy and therefore illegal (IANAL).

Comment: This is not clear. At first sight, I had understood "a clear option to opt-out is a clear violation". The opposite of what you certainly want to say.

Answer (score 1):

What happens with many mobile carriers and ISPs is that whenever a user does not have enough credit on their top-up account (for prepaid users) or when a postpaid account has been suspended for whatever reason, their DNS replaces all regular responses so that the user is directed towards a captive portal that tells the user either to top-up their account to continue using the Internet, or to contact their carrier to fix whatever is wrong with their account. This is common practice all over the world. Similar thing happens with other networks which use captive portals in order to block access to the Internet (Airport and hotel WiFi networks are common examples).

So, if the HTTP request is not for the top-level HTML document, but rather for a script-src, style-src, etc. then CSP blocks the redirect to whatever domain the DNS mangling from the captive portal results in. Redirect handling in CSP is not uniform across browsers (even within different versions of the same browser), so these events might only be reported by some User-Agents.